# Rejecting a change should allow more than 150 characters

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, documentation

Initial changes to the pre-generated documentation topics can be substantial, and 150 characters seems a bit short when explaining why you reject a change.

In fact, the instructions for the 'other' reason tell you to be detailed, as @AndrasDeak indicates in the comments.

Can this limit be increased?

Comment: Agreed, I've run into this a lot because often the reason I'm rejecting something is because I feel it would be better suited as an example under an existing topic, rather than a new one, and I like to be helpful and provide the link to that topic... but the URL does eat a whole lot of characters :)

Comment: [Here's my case](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OUvyD.png), complete with free-hand circles. How does "be detailed" go with twitter-like brevity? "*Ur edit is rong m8 #fail*". I was going to write your post, only tagged [bug].

Comment: @AndrasDeak I hadn't noticed that yet. I've added the [meta-tag:bug] tag.

Comment: Maybe an FR to introduce short links as well? Something like: `http://stackoverflow.com/d/2307`? cc @AndrasDeak

Comment: @rene that could be a compromise, but I'd prefer a longer text box (at least as long as one for a custom mod flag)

Comment: @rene There are some shortlinks, though not quite as short - `http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/t/{id}` for topics and `http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/{id}` for examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As part of requiring a comment on proposed changes rejected as Copied Content, we're increasing the max comment length to 500.

With you in the next build.